# Window Server Domain DNS

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

I have setup a Windows server, installed an Active Directory domain, but I am unable to add my other office computers to the domain due to this error:

"An attempt to resolve the DNS name of domain controller in the domain being joined has failed. Please verify this client is configured to reach a DNS Server that can resolve DNS names."

**SERVER SETUP:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should do what it advised you to do.

Comment: `1.` Your server has no primary DNS suffix, which is odd if you did in fact create an AD domain. `2.` The server should not use 127.0.0.1 for primary DNS. `3.` The server should not use anything other than AD DNS servers for DNS. Your secondary DNS appears to be a Cogent ip address, which may be the ip address assigned to you via your ISP and is certainly not the DNS server you want to use for your AD clients, including the server itself.

Answer (score 1):

All computers in an Active Directory domain ***must*** use domain controllers as their DNS servers, and only them.

In your case, this means the server must use 192.168.2.8 (or 127.0.0.1) as ist DNS server, but ***not*** 66.28.0.61.

All other computers must use 192.168.2.8, ***and only that***.

Answer (score 0):

What is your client IP settings? Do you have 192.168.2.8 as DNS server configured. You can try to ping the domain Netbios name from your client to see if it gets translated correctly. This has to work prior joining the domain.

Comment: Should ping the DNS domain name

Comment: yea sure, my bad. :)